# NumPy 2D array Ordinary Slicing vs Boolean based Slicing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to Numpy, and I was experimenting with 2D Arrays Numpy, 
I made the following observations when an array is sliced in 2 different ways

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
slice1 = a[:,:3]
slice1[0,0] = 100
print(a) 
-- gives, 100 2 3 4 5
           1  2 3 4 5
```

This behaviour is expected as per numpy docs 
But Consider this slicing

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
slice2 = a[[True,True],:3]
slice2[0,0] = 100
print(a) 
-- gives us
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Could anyone explain the difference between these 2 approaches

Comment: [Advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) always returns a copy of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a [view](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/glossary.html#term-view)).

Answer (score 2):

From the [NumPy indexing documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> Advanced indexing always returns a *copy* of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a [*view*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/glossary.html#term-view)).

After all, there's no way to make the strides work if you want to make `some_arr[[True, False, False, True, True, False]]` return a view.